# How to get the unique column values for the other column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Please refer to this image Look at C and D column.

[image]
How many unique "week number" a "day" have.
For example how many unique week number sunday have, monday and so on,

Basically i want to know how many different monday(different date), how many different friday, and so on,  occur in the C column.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `"1/COUNTIFS"` scheme which is "magic" for problems involving uniqueness.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($C$2:$C$15="Sunday")/COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$15,$C$2:$C$15,$D$2:$D$15,$D$2:$D$15))
```

But be careful that this formula needs that your ranges have no blank gaps. also always avoid full (or too large) columns for formulas involving array computations,  because they're slow.

p.s. you can replace the literal "Sunday" with any cell reference.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer, But i need this for all days in the week, Not only for sunday

Comment: @beginner IIUC, you need to count the total number of unique combinations (day, weekNumber)? Otherwise you can put the week days below each other somewhere and reference their cells in the formula.

Comment: Sorry I am totally new to Excel. i don't get you . I want something like these `Sunday=>week_number23 ,week_number24....` So that i can count these week number to find out how many times Sunday (different days) occur. Can't we use pivot for this.  Is there any other easy way to do so,

Comment: @beginner I understood that you wanted to *count* them, not to *list* them (see *"how many"* in your question). May be you can have the list with pivot tables idk.

Comment: I think that *he* thinks that it has to be done in two steps.    
@beginner, you don't have to do it in two steps. The formula that ASH gave you will calculate how many distinct Sundays are in the array.  Copy and paste the formula into a cell to test it.  For other days of the week, just change "Sunday" to "Monday" or any other day.

Comment: i just copy paste the formula in cell. doesn't work,It just changes some values to 1.  please help,

Comment: @beginner all the arrays in my formula end at `row 15`. change this number to your actual last row (in the five places).

Comment: Still not working, Ok let it go, Thanks for your help. I think i have to calculate these manually. will take lot's of time